# eth_subscribe for logs on alchemy

Tags: logs, alchemy

I am trying to subscribe to log events on ETH mainnet using alchemy provider as explained [here](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/apis/ethereum/eth-subscribe-1#logs)

The subscription request returns successful response but I am not receiving any notifications at all

Here is the wscat logs:

```
wscat -c wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<redacted>
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
{"method":"eth_subscribe","params":["logs", {"fromBlock":"latest","toBlock":"latest","address":"<redacted>","topics:["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
< {"id":1,"result":"0x646ea02a49d579f15112918d76983131","jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

I did some ERC-20 transactions and checked their logs and the address and the topic matches but I get no notifications. Any idea if this works as intended or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For the way you subscribe to the event:

`{"method":"eth_subscribe","params":["logs", {"fromBlock":"latest","toBlock":"latest","address":"<redacted>","topics:["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}`

You should remove "fromBlock" and "toBlock":
`{"method":"eth_subscribe","params":["logs", {"address":"<redacted>","topics:["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}`

To receive notifications.